# "Too many characters in character literal error"

Tags: c#, char

I'm struggling with a piece of code and getting the error:

> Too many characters in character literal error

Using C# and switch statement to iterate through a string buffer and reading tokens, but getting the error in this line:

> case '&&':
>
> case '||':
>
> case '==':

How can I keep the `==` and `&&` as a char?

Comment: Those aren't single characters...

Answer (score 154):

This is because, in C#, single quotes (`''`) denote (or encapsulate) a single character, whereas double quotes (`""`) are used for a string of characters. For example:

```
var myChar = '=';

var myString = "==";
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example:

```
char myChar = '|';
string myString = "||";
```

Chars are delimited by single quotes, and strings by double quotes.

The good news is C# switch statements work with strings!

```
switch (mytoken)
{
    case "==":
        //Something here.
        break;
    default:
        //Handle when no token is found.
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot treat `==` or `||` as chars, since they are not chars, but a sequence of chars.

You could make your switch...case work on strings instead.

Answer (score 2):

A char can hold a single character only, a character literal is a single character in single quote, i.e. `'&'` - if you have more characters than one you want to use a string, for that you have to use double quotes:

```
case "&&":
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.
`String.Replace('\\.','')` is not valid statement and throws the same error.
Thanks to C# we can use double quotes instead of single quotes and following works
`String.Replace("\\.","")`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this using a Unicode encoding, but I doubt this is what you really want.

The `==` is the unicode value 2A76 so I belive you can do this:

```
char c = '\u2A76';
```

I can't test this at the moment but I'd be interested to know if that works for you.

You will need to dig around for the others.  Here is a unicode table if you want to look:

http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

Comment: U+2A76 is 'THREE CONSECUTIVE EQUALS SIGNS', not two (cf: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a76). And it has nothing to do with the character sequence `==` as you would find it in a typical source file.